# Alamofire parameters conflict

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm unable to perform PUT request with latest version of Alamofire.

This sample work :

```
Alamofire.request(endpoint, method: .put, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
```

But this :

```
Alamofire.request(endpoint, method: .put, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
```

doesn't, i'm unable to compile and i get `Extra argument 'method' in call` error

Why putting a parameter do that ?

Comment: Can you show us how do you create parameters - more exactly what is the type of parameters

Comment: Thank's @NickCatib, your comment pointed me to the problem, ma parameter array wasn't formed correctly...

Comment: Np, I will post this suggestion as the answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is the problem with compiler that will say that there is extra argument when actually there is issue with types.

You have to ensure that your parameters that you are sending correspond to function signature.